# How to use Twitter get search/tweets api 1.1 with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, oauth, vbscript, twitter

I already know that new twitter api 1.1 requires oauth1.0 athentication for searchs, but i don't know how to implement this on classic ASP.

I have been trying this: http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/ but i haven`t be able to use it for search in twitter. I want to find all tweets that contains some specific words.
On previous twitter api it would be: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20green
So twitter search tweets containing 'blue' and 'green'

does anyone can show me any example of how to do this with the new api?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this all with sending/reading HTTP Requests to twitter.  How to do an HTTP Request, you can look here:

[HTTP GET Request, ASP - I'm lost!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885170/http-get-request-asp-im-lost)

[How to perform an HTTP POST request in ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463635/how-to-perform-an-http-post-request-in-asp)

But here is a classic asp script online for oAuth that can be used for your situation, and can be seen/downloaded here:
http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/